# My app to measure pulse oximetry is rejected by Apple

Tags: ios, camera, measure

I made the free app to measure the oxygen level in blood using a phone's camera.

Apple rejected app said this:

> Guideline 1.4.1 - Safety - Physical Harm
>
> We noticed that your app claims to take health measurements using only
>   iOS device sensors, which is not a functionality these device sensors
>   support.
>
> Specifically, your app claims to measure a user’s bloody oxygen
>   saturation.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please remove any unverified health measuring
>   functionality from your app that uses the device sensors.
>
> Alternatively, you may submit documentation in the App Review
>   Information section in App Store Connect that clearly discloses data
>   and methodology to support accuracy claims relating to these health
>   measurements. If the level of accuracy or methodology cannot be
>   validated, we will reject your app.

What documentation I have to submit?

Comment: Hey how did you fixed this

Comment: Is it because iOS device sensors do not measure spo2, only watchOS sensors do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to conduct some tests using a real pulse oximeter, and your app, to show that your app gives similar readings to the pulse oximeter.

The tests would need to be thorough enough to convince a sane person that your app is decently accurate compared with a real pulse oximeter.

Apple needs to know that your app is accurate before it allows people to use it.

Basically you need to do some science ⚗️. For example, multiple tests on a number of different people of varying health / age / skin tone. Document your experiments. Attach the findings. Apple wants to see that.